# Inicializar design system en un panel sd (GX18 UP3)

Tags: genexus

gx18 UP3

Alguien sabe como inicializar un design system en un panel sd

Tengo lo siguiente:

Event Start
&option = "Dark"
DesignSystem.SetOption("color-scheme", &option)
Endevent

y al ejecutar entrega el siguiente error:
error spc0200: External Object GeneXus\Common\UI\DesignSystem does not implement method 'setoption(' for .NET Web environment. (Panel 'SRDCorp.MenuSRDCorp', Details)

Comment: Coloca ese código en el evento ClientStart